# User registration form without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserModel userModel)
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon= new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        String query = "INSERT INTO User VALUES(@UserName, @UserPassword, @UserAddress)";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query,sqlCon);

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",userModel.username);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", userModel.userpassword);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserAddress", userModel.useraddress);

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I'm learning C#. I tried to code CURD operations. In this code there is is a `Open()` method. I want to know why it used and explain line by line what is code  flow.

Comment: I guess it's better for you to read this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Open() method opens SQL connection to communicate with SQL and you should close the connection by sqlCon.Close(). otherwise initiated connection will remain unclosed and you might get exceptions on sqlCon.Open()

Comment: Under absolutely no circumstances should you ever be storing plain passwords in a database - they must be hashed and salted. Do not try and reinvent the wheel

Comment: And [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing any database operation from external applications. You need to establish a connection between the database and your application.
To establish a connection between database and your application you must require database "ConnectionString" this connection string is mandatory for performing CRUD operation from any external application.

```
SqlConnection sqlCon= new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

To establish a database connection we are using

```
sqlCon.Open();
```

It is better to mention your connection string in web.config file. Because it is highly secured.

Answer (score 1):

In your code Open() method is use for database connection open. You can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx Microsoft document.

```
 sqlCon.Open();
```

To open database connection

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO User VALUES(@UserName,@UserPassword,@UserAddress)";
```

Database query

```
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query,sqlCon);
```

To create database command

```
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",userModel.username);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", userModel.userpassword);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserAddress", userModel.useraddress);
```

These are the parameters to pass with command

```
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will execute your command to open database